# Using x-path " | " operator

Tags: xpath

I can choose several paths using `.//div/h1/text() | .//div/h2/text()`. However I would like to know if there's a way of doing it without explicitly writing out the part that is common for both path's - in this case `.//div/` - every time?

Comment: If you're asking questions about XPath, you really need to say whether you're interested in XPath 1.0 or 2.0, since the answers are often different, and both versions are in widespread use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for shortcuts, with XPath 2.0 you can shorten e.g. `//div/h1 | //div/h2` to e.g. `//div/(h1 | h2)` but that syntax is not allowed in XPath 1.0. And I think XPath 3.0 will introduce a `let` clause to define variables. So there I think you can do e.g. `let $r := /html/body/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[5] return ($r/span | $r/a)`.

Or for your corrected sample with XPath 2.0 you can shorten `.//div/h1/text() | .//div/h2/text()` to `.//div/(h1/text() | h2/text())`. But with XPath 1.0 all you can do is use `.//div/*[self::h1 | self::h2]/text()`.

Comment: corrected the mistake - expressions were meant to be different. thanks, for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
    .//div/*[self::h1 or self::h2]/text()
```

**In Xpath 2.0 one can use**:

```
    .//div/(h1|h2)/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

`.//div/*[(local-name() = 'h1') or (local-name() = 'h2')]/text()`

should do the trick